# Flow Variable of Email addresses to Invocable Apex action

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, singleemailmessage, invocable-method, apex-variable

I'm trying to pass in the flow variable collection of Email addresses to Apex action to send out one email to each email address. I got some idea from [Question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/304475/pass-variables-from-flow-to-apex-cannot-access-invocable-variable), the code works fine when i ran it from anonymous window (by passing list of Email addresses) but it doesn't work with the flow.  Can someone point me what I'm doing wrong?

Here is the code

```
public class SendEmailAction {
    @InvocableMethod(label='Send SE Email Notification') 
public static void SendSENotification(List<List<String>> Emailaddresses){
    List<String> getEmails = new List<String>();
    
    //List<string> getEmail = Emailaddresses[0];
    List<OrgWideEmailAddress> lstEmailAddress=[select Id from OrgWideEmailAddress WHERE Address='tripss@rush.edu'];
    List<EmailTemplate> SEEmailTemplate= [Select Id, Name, DeveloperName 
                           from EmailTemplate 
                           where DeveloperName= 'Safety_Event_New_Event_Reported'];
         
     Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] mails = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[0];
            
    for(List<String> Ids : Emailaddresses) {
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        mail.setTemplateId(SEEmailTemplate[0].Id);
        mail.setTargetObjectId(UserInfo.getUserId());
        mail.setToAddresses(getemails);
        mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
        mails.add(mail);
        mail.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(lstEmailAddress[0].Id);
    }
   Messaging.sendEmail(mails);
}
}
```

Flow
[image: Flow]

[image: LOOP]

[image: Assignments]

[image]

Comment: the code you posted doesn't compile as `getemails` is not declared. Is `Ids` supposed to be `getemails` ?

Comment: Yes Sorry I'm new in apex, Ids supposed to getEmails. Do you know what I'm doing wrong in this code?

Comment: please use [edit] to make the code posted correct; also use [edit] to show the loop, assignment, and apex action details (screen shots). Plus Summer 21 allows you to use the [Debug option on record triggered flows](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_automate_flow_debug_record_triggered_flows.htm&type=5&release=232) and that is immensely useful at figuring out the issue with your flow

Comment: Thanks for the info. Sorry I meant the code is suppose to get all email addresses from collection and send out email to each one of them. Ids are still Emailaddresses. I'm not sure if thats the correct way to do it. I added the screen shots of Loop, assignments and Email action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work:

```
public class SendEmailAction {
  @InvocableMethod(label='Send SE Email Notification') 
  public static void SendSENotification(List<List<String>> emailAddressCollections){
    
    List<OrgWideEmailAddress> lstEmailAddress=[SELECT Id 
                          FROM OrgWideEmailAddress 
                          WHERE Address='tripss@rush.edu'];
    List<EmailTemplate> SEEmailTemplate= [SELECT Id, Name, DeveloperName 
                           FROM EmailTemplate 
                           WHERE DeveloperName= 'Safety_Event_New_Event_Reported'];
         
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] mails = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[0];
            
    for(List<String> emailAddresses : emailAddressCollections) {
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        mail.setTemplateId(SEEmailTemplate[0].Id);
        mail.setTargetObjectId(UserInfo.getUserId());
        mail.setToAddresses(emailAddresses);
        mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
        mails.add(mail);
        mail.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(lstEmailAddress[0].Id);
    }
    Messaging.sendEmail(mails);
  }
}
```

I renamed your variables to be a bit clearer (as you are dealing with lists of lists)

Your flow looks OK as far as I can see. use the [Summer 21 Record-Triggered Flow debugging](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_automate_flow_debug_record_triggered_flows.htm&type=5&release=232) to make sure that a collection of strings are passed in the flow interview to the invocable apex. If not, dig deeper into the Flow

Comment: Thank you, the code seems to be working via anonymous window but it still doesn't work with the flow, when i debug it passes the input as collection of email addresses [ test@test.edu, test1@test.edu....]. I doubt the apex parameter is accepting this type of collection. Perhaps, do you think we should pull the object Id's instead and  inpur Ids as parameter and pull the email addresses via SOQL in Apex class and then send the  Messaging.SingleEmailMessage?

Comment: well, I built a little flow that looped across some sobjects, building a text collection that I passed in to an invocable apex method just like yours.  All the text collection elements were present. `List<List<String>>` is definitely supported.

Comment: Since this was a record trigger flow , I created another test schedule flow to debug little deeper. I built a text collection of email addresses and called the apex action. The flow failed with error"  An Apex error occurred: System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS, The target object's email address "antonio.dabraio@00d4p000001dzqhuay" is not valid: [targetObjectId, 0054P00000Arw0WQAR]", I will ask another question if its going out of original question.

Comment: Answering my question re: target object's email address, I setTreatTargetObjectAsRecipient(false); and voila it worked!!. Thanks a ton